# Search and replace control characters (^@, ^M, ^I....) in vi

Tags: vi, special-characters

I copied this line from `/proc/some_proc_id/cmdline` in my ubuntu machine,

```
java^@-jar^@/usr/lib/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar^@-port^@4444^@-trustAllSSLCertificates^@
```

Somehow, the space characters are represented by `^@` in vi. I tried to replace them with space characters using the command,

```
:%s#^@# #g
```

But it says, `pattern not found ^@`.

How can one replace special characters particularly those that start with carat symbol?

Comment: What is the terminal type you are using?

Comment: at times, `TERM` and many times, it is `screen`

Comment: What is the terminal program you are using and is the `TERM` environment variable set correctly?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Somehow, the space characters are represented by `^@` in vi.

It's not `vi` that did that. Although you type command lines in shells with spaces between the arguments, command lines are actually discrete sequences of strings internally, not one long space-separated string. The shell separated the command line into individual argument strings before the command was launched.

In C, strings are terminated with NUL characters and those are shown as `^@`.

> How can one replace special characters particularly those that start with carat symbol?

In order to type those characters, you must prefix them with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> for literal next character.

For example in this case: <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>@</kbd>.

The special character that introduces literal next characters is normally <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> but it is actually configurable. Type `stty -a` to find out what it is set to. Look for `lnext` in the output.

Comment: the post is informative.. but the real solution for my question is escaping the carat symbol - `:%s#^@##g`. Since i copy, pasted from terminal, vi has pasted them as original characters...

Comment: @MadhavanKumar You don't escape the caret symbol, because there *is* no caret symbol. It's really an actual control character. `^letter` is just visual notation for that, no real caret involved. And yes, you have to escape the control character, the Ctrl-V is how you do that from the keyboard. That works most everywhere. FYI, the other answer contains an alternative, specific to `vi`'s command line, to avoid having to type the control character at all.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar If your terminal displayed the NUL characters as the two-character string `^@` and you copy-pasted that, then use `\^@` to represent that two-character string in vi. A lot of software uses backslash to mean “interpret the next character literally instead of using its special function”.

Comment: @Gilles, you are right.. that is what i tried to convey to Celada....

Answer (score 7):

That *symbol* represents a NULL character, with ASCII value 000.

You could try:

```
:%s/\%x00/ /g
```

## Alternative:

On a keyboard where the @ symbol is on top of the <kbd>2</kbd> key (thanks Celada) you can do:

- `%s/<CTRL-2>/ /g` (on PC)
- `%s/<CTRL-SHIFT-2>/ /g` (on Mac)

where `<CTRL-2>` means first press down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> on PC, keeping it as pressed down, hit <kbd>2</kbd>, release <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

and `<CTRL-SHIFT-2>` means first press down the <kbd>control</kbd> on Mac, keeping it as pressed down, press down <kbd>shift</kbd> on Mac, keeping it as pressed down, hit <kbd>2</kbd>, release <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>.

Finally, both of the two commands should result in `%s/^@/ /g` on screen. `^@` means a single character, not `^` followed by `@`, so you can't just type `^` and `@` in a row in the above command.

This command replaces all the `^@` with space characters.

([Source](https://superuser.com/q/75130/180675))

Comment: When you say "PC", do you mean Windows?

Comment: CTRL-2 and CTRL-SHIFT-2 only make sense on keyboard layouts where the `@` is on top of the `2` key.

Comment: @Sparhawk: No, I mean a linux pc. :-)

Comment: Why CTRL? I've never seen a system where CTRL is the key used to shift between the different meaning of a key. That's normally SHIFT.

Comment: It is strange (maybe a bug in vim?), but it works. It should usually be ctrl+shift+2 (on a us-keyboard). Ask it as a separate question or ask the vim developers. Anyhow Celada’s answer is more general for control-characters.

Comment: @erik For me, `vi --version` returns "VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled <…>)" on both Mac and Linux. Maybe your text editor has a platform dependency, but Mac isn't inherently different from Linux in this way.

Comment: @Potatoswatter does that mean, that you can create the `^@` symbol with both crtl+2 and ctrl+shift+2 on both computers/operating systems? Or what are you trying to tell me?

Comment: @erik I don't think it makes sense to frame this as a "Mac/PC" difference because the hardware is essentially the same. Checking now, Vim on Ubuntu Linux recognizes both ctrl-2 and ctrl-shift-2, and on Mac indeed requires the shift… but it's still more likely a "BSD/Linux" difference. Perhaps their ncurses libraries diverged.

Comment: `\%x00` works great for search string, but how do you use it in a replace string?

Answer (score -2):

OK, here is the simple explanation, which assumes you are not a computer expert! In the vi editor, (and possibly in vim, although I personally don't use that) press Esc to get out of Insert mode, then search for the ^@ characters using /%x00 and you can then delete each one (using the x key). Use n (for next) to skip to the next one, then x that one too.
This is handy if you only have a few to delete, as, after the first search (the /%x00) you can just do n x n x n x ... until you got them all!
Of course, if you have a big file with loads of them to delete, you'll need to do a "search and replace" operation. Make sure you are not in Insert mode by pressing the Esc key (it won't do any harm to press it more than once) then Shift-; to get the : prompt at the bottom left of your screen. (That's holding down the Shift key whilst pressing the ; key.) Type 1,$s/%x00//g (it will appear after the :) and press Enter. The ^@ characters will all disappear! What you just did was: For all lines in this file (the 1,$ bit) substitute (the s bit) wherever you see a ^@ (the %x00 bit) with nothing at all (the // bit, which you will note has nothing between the two forward slashes) and do this as many times as necessary on each line (the g bit, where g stands for globally.)
If you wanted not to delete the characters but replace each one, it's the same command but put the character you want to replace them with between the //. Don't forget that \n is the newline character in unix etc, so you might want to use that. Or any string of characters you like, of course.
Hope that helps!

Comment: (1) The question shows that the OP already knows how to get into command mode in `vi`, so that part of your answer is superfluous.  (2) We generally assume that users who can access Stack Exchange on the Internet already know how to type.  We hardly ever tell people when they need to type “Enter”, and we never explain that you need to press and hold “Shift” to type capital letters.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  So you really don’t need to explain how to type a colon.  (And please don’t explain how to type `$` or `%`, either). (3) It goes beyond unnecessary to simply wrong.  Command mode in `vi` is activated by typing a COLON.  Colon is not always Shift+Semicolon (there are other keyboard layouts). (4) Why do you mention `\n`? In `vi`, `s/something/\n/` doesn’t insert newlines.