# how to search for special characters starting with ~(tild) in vi

Tags: vi, text, special-characters

when I want to search for special character `^H` in vi, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in sequence. If I want to search for special characters displayed like `~@~X`, how can I search those characters? (like figure below seen in vi)
What I want to do is to remove those `~@~X` or `~@~Y` patterns.(in regex, `~@~`.). I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> and other things but they didn't work.

[image]

Comment: @DarkHeart thanks for the edit. How do I use the keyboard shaped character buttons in edit?

Comment: `<kbd>` is the tag for the keyboard shapes.

Answer (score 0):

I found from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217010/search-and-replace-control-characters-m-i-in-vi?rq=1) that we can search for any ascii pattern. I tested with ghex2 what the ascii codes are for ~@X or ~@Y. They were 0xe2 0x80 0x58(or 0x59). So in vi, I can do search and replacement like `:%s/\%xe2\%x80.//g`.